# Map does not fire Pointer Pressed/Release events

Tags: codenameone

I have a MapContainer instance that does not respond to attached PointerRelease listeners. I'm trying to detect when the map has stopped moving once it's been dragged by the user. In the code below the first two listeners do not produce any output. Third/Fourth do.

```
MapContainer mc = new MapContainer("mykey");
mc.addPointerPressedListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Don't see this");
            }
        });


        mc.addPointerReleasedListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Don't see this either");
            }
        });
        mc.addTapListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("See This :-)");
            }
        });
        mc.addMapListener(new MapListener() {
            @Override
            public void mapPositionUpdated(Component source, int zoom, Coord centerCoord) {
                System.out.println("See this too!");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addTapListener` is correct and implemented in `MapContainer`. The low level pointer events won't work properly for that container because the map logic is implemented natively and thus these events are consumed.

You might be able to track them by binding a listener to the parent form but that's problematic as events/gestures might have platform specific interpretations.